# Logo in Mediawiki Medik Skin not visible in responsive version

Tags: mediawiki, skin, medik

I have switched my Mediawiki to [Medik skin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Medik).

However, I have trouble making the logo visible on my mobile. I am aware that without any further configuration, no logo is visible.

Setting the option

```
$wgMedikShowLogo= 'sidebar'
```

should make the logo visible in the sidebar, however, this does not work on mobiles, no logo shows. The option 'main' does also not work for mobiles, no logo visible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set [`$wgLogos`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLogos) in your LocalSettings.php. Also, logo in the sidebar is hidden on mobile screens. If you want the logo to be visible on all devices, use `$wgMedikShowLogo= 'main'`. (But for further investigation, you'll have to provide your wiki's URL.)